# Could not find file 'bin\Antlr3.Runtime.pdb' Error when creating deployment package

Tags: c#, antlr, nuget-package

I'm getting the following error when tried to create deployment package.

```
"Copying file bin\Antlr3.Runtime.pdb to obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\Antlr3.Runtime.pdb failed. Could not find file 'bin\Antlr3.Runtime.pdb'"
```

Can someone tell me what is happening and how to solve it

Answer (score 6):

1. First of all delete whole file from bin folder
2. Remove reference of this "Antlr3"
3. Close Visual Studio
4. Open .croj project file in Notepad
5. find 'Antlr3.Runtime.pdb' and you found this in "ItemGroup". [See ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ6JB.png)
6. Remove below lines and save file.
7. Open project and re-rebuild solution.

It's working fine for me. Let me update here this is work for you???

Comment: Answering questions from years ago with no accepted answers is nice, but a little in vain

Answer (score 1):

For some reason "Clean" and "Rebuild" leaves the dll in the bin folder, but don't bring the missing .pdb.
The manual deletion of the entire bin's content and consequent "Rebuild" does the job